# Extracting data from a 3D scatter plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm writing an interface for making 3D scatter plots in matplotlib, and I'd like to  access the data from a python script. For a 2D scatter plot, I know the process would be:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
h = ax.scatter(x,y,c=c,s=15,vmin=0,vmax=1,cmap='hot')
data = h.get_offsets()
```

With the above code, I know that data would be a `(N,2)` numpy array populated with my `(x,y)` data. When I try to perform the same operation for 3D data:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
h = ax.scatter(x,y,z,c=c,s=15,cmap='hot',vmin=0,vmax=1)
data = h.get_offsets()
```

The resulting `data` variable is still an `(N,2)` numpy array rather than a `(N,3)` numpy array. The contents of `data` no longer match any of my input data; I assume that `data` is populated with the 2D projections of my 3D data, but I would really like to access the 3D data used to generate the scatter plot. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, the coordinates obtained via `get_offsets` are the projected coordinates. 
The original coordinates are hidden inside the `mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d.Path3DCollection` which is returned by the `scatter` in three dimensional axes. You would obtain the original coordinates from the `._offsets3d` attribute. (This is a "private" attribute, but unfortunately the only way to retrieve this information.)

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
x = [1,2,3,4]
y = [1,3,3,5]
z = [10,20,30,40]
c= [1,2,3,1]
scatter = ax.scatter(x,y,z,c=c,s=15,cmap='hot',vmin=0,vmax=1)
data = np.array(scatter._offsets3d).T
print(scatter)  # prints mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d.Path3DCollection
print(data)

# prints
# 
# [[  1.   1.  10.]
#  [  2.   3.  20.]
#  [  3.   3.  30.]
#  [  4.   5.  40.]]
```

Comment: As a follow-on, is it possible to use `._offsets3d` from to update/change the plotted data?

Comment: Yes, that is possible.

Comment: Isn't it possible to access this data using `ax` instead?

Comment: It think it could be accessed via `ax` using `ax.collections[0]._offsets3d`.