# Matplotlib: Retrieve rgba from 3D scatter plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, scatter-plot, scatter3d

I have a 3D scatter plot like this:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

x = np.random.random(10)
y = np.random.random(10)
z = np.random.random(10)
rgba = np.random.random((10, 4))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
artist = ax.scatter(x, y, z, c=rgba)
```

As demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51716696/extracting-data-from-a-3d-scatter-plot-in-matplotlib), I can retrieve the `x`, `y` and `z` data from the scatter `artist` using the `_offsets3d` attribute:

```
x2, y2, z2 = artist._offsets3d
print(all(x == x2))  # True
print(all(y == y2))  # True
print(all(z == z2))  # True
```

I seek a similar way to get back the `rgba` data from `artist`. I actually only need the alpha values, but I guess the color and alpha remain stored together.

I use matplotlib 3.0.0 if it matters.

Comment: I think you want `artist.get_array()`?

Comment: `Axes.scatter` returns a `PathCollection` object (https://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PathCollection). The most likely method you're after is either `get_alpha()`, or `get_facecolor()`.

Comment: `artist.get_facecolor()` works!